# Sentence without object pronoun

Tags: ellipsis

I've just read this sentence in a English vocabulary book:

> **a)** I'm very pleased you are going to visit next week

The context: This person is very pleased to receive the visit of a friend.

So, mustn't be added the object pronoun **me**?

> **b)** I'm very pleased you are going to visit **me** next week.

Or, is **a)** also valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **a)** is also valid. If you look at Merriam-Webster's definition (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visit), you will see that *visit* can be both transitive (that is, take an object) and intransitive (without an object):

> intransitive verb
>     :  to make a visit; also :  to make frequent or regular visits

Comment: What I apprehend is that visit-intransitive can be used here because both people know the context.  But is there cases where **visit** must be transitive? For instance: A: _'Have you decided whom are you going to visit?'_ B:'Yes, I am going to visit.' If this happens, there is no communication. So, is the intransitive form of **visit** always optional or are there situations where we can't use the intransitive, only the transitive?

Comment: Yes, there are definitely situations where the intransitive form makes no sense. Your example is an excellent illustration of that.

Comment: Thank you:) I needed these confirmation words. I think now I understand. Thank you again!